# When do you use OpenID vs. OpenID Connect

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, openid, openid-connect

Can they be used together? ....or are they two separate protocols that may or may not be useful depending on the context?

The reason I ask is because I'm trying to implement the following:

1. User "Bob" goes to a Client implemented as a User-Agent only application.
2. The protected resources are controlled by the same domain as the authentication/authorization server, but they are on different subdomains. However, no session is found in the cookies, so...
3. Bob clicks "login," and gets redirected to authorization/authentication server using something like the following:

   ```
   GET https://accounts.example.com/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=123&redirect_uri=http://original.example.com&scope=openid profile token custom
   ```
4. Bob is given a list of options to choose from to authenticate, i.e., "example, google, twitter," etc. which leads to his authentication at example.com, which in turn is used for his authorization for a specific API hosted by example.com.

Should I be using OpenID Connect, OpenID 2.0, both? What? This is my first time implementing any of them. I'm only asking about the authentication part of this. I'm just trying to get Bob authenticated so that I can move on to issuing the token to the client.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I don't think either of the other previous responses answer the question, which is asking the difference between `OpenID Connect` and `OpenID 2.0`.  `OpenID 2.0` is not `OAuth 2.0`.

`OpenID 2.0` and `OpenID Connect` are very different standards with completely different parameters and response body formats.  Both are built on top of `OAuth 2.0` by putting additional values into otherwise valid `OAuth 2.0` requests and responses, in order to provide identity information needed for authentication (whereas `OAuth 2.0` only provides authorization, not authentication).  OpenID Connect improved naming and structure of `OpenID 2.0` fields and parameters in order to be easier to use.  I can easily read the `OpenID Connect` specification and understand what all the values are used for and what to set them to, but trying to read the `OpenID 2.0` specification is a bit more difficult and convoluted.

At this point the choice is easy, `OpenID 2.0` is deprecated.  You should use `OpenID Connect`.

Comment: The only answer that answers the question

Comment: Agreed. I think people should spend the time reading and understanding the question before answering.

Comment: Looking through OpenID FAQ, https://openid.net/connect/faq/, `OpenID Connect `is the newer protocol then `OpenID 2`, so it make sense we should use `Open ID Connect` instead of `OpenID 2`

Comment: can I conclude that Open ID Connect is used for both authentication and authorization? or I should use Open ID Connect for authentication only and also implement OAuth2 for authorization?

Comment: `OpenID Connect` itself only concerns authentication. `OAuth2` handles authorization. However since `OpenID Connect` piggybacks on top of `OAuth2`, you can and often will have `OAuth2` values alongside `OpenID Connect` values in both the request parameters and the response payloads. For example you can add the `openid` scope to the `OAuth2` scope param alongside other `OAuth2` scopes, to signal that you desire authentication along with any `OAuth2` authorizations being performed. On the provider backend they are likely to be implemented alongside each other because of the payload sharing.

Comment: @theferrit32 Where do you find that OpenID 2.0 is deprecated? It looks like it is still alive and kicking to me.

Comment: @JonathanWilbur It actually is superseded by OpenID Connect (https://openid.net/developers/libraries/obsolete/).

Comment: @theferrit32 Is OpenID 2.0 built on top of OAuth2.0? As far as I know OpenID 1.0 and OpenID 2.0 were developed well before OAuth 1.0 and OAuth 2.0 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)

Answer (score 24):

OpenID and OpenID Connect are both for *authentication*, not for *authorization*. The two activities are distinct. OpenID Connect is in fact OAuth (an authorization protocol) which is turned (abused) into an authentication protocol. More explanations in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/44614/655).

To some extent you can mix authentication and authorization, but that's a source of confusion. In your case, you apparently want to *authenticate* users with "Google, Twitter,...": you want Google (or Twitter) to tell you who the user *is*, but not what the user *should be allowed to do*; you want these external providers for authentication, not authorization.

Another way to see it is the following: a user connects to your server *S*. Server *S* offers some "services", i.e. will do "things" when asked for; however, it won't accept to do the same things for everybody. Let's assume that you found it fit to give control of what *S* may do or not for each user to another system which we will call *R*. *R* may or may not be the same computer as *S*, but let's think generically and assume that *R* is distinct from *S*. From the point of view of *S*, the needed information is in scope of authorization: *S* wants to know whether the call is to be granted or not. So there will be some authorization protocol going on between *S* and *R*. Possibly, *S* and *R* won't talk directly to each other, but only through messages ("tickets") which are transported by the client; that's a technical detail.

However, to decide whether a given request to *S* should be allowed or not, the authorization server *R* must know *who* is sending the request, because the answer depends on the user's identity. Therefore, *R* will need to authenticate the user; or, more generically, to talk to an authentication server *T*. *T* is responsible for making sure that the user is indeed who he claims to be. An authentication protocol then occurs between *R* and *T*.

In your example, *R* is your authorization server, while *T* is Google/Twitter. You would use OpenID between *R* and *T*, and OAuth between *S* and *R*.

OpenID Connect is when *S* wants to do some authentication as well; *S* then uses *R* (who "speaks OAuth") and infers that if *R* allows the request, then *R* must have done some sort of authentication of the user; so *S* decides that the user is indeed who he claims to be, since it (implicitly) convinced *R*.

Comment: This bit threw me off a little, because I think OpenID Connect and OAuth are not precisely equivalent: "OpenID Connect is in fact OAuth (an authorization protocol) which is turned (abused) into an authentication protocol.".  From what I can tell from https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/, OpenID Connect deals with some of the pitfalls that would be encountered using plain OAuth for pseudo-authentication

Comment: @ossek You are correct.  I would not classify OIDC as an "abuse" of OAuth.  I feel that word is probably misleading as well.  OIDC is built on top of OAuth.  It uses OAuth to authorize the client service (S in the above example) to access the calling user's identity.

Comment: I would also rephrase the last paragraph as.  “With OIDC there is another service I that S trusts.  This service can tell you the identity of the current user.  S wants to ask I for this identity.  I must first authorize that S is allowed access to that identity.  This authorization is done with OAuth (e.g.  S gets a key from R and sends it to I and I verifies that key with R before answering).

Comment: @ThomasPornin, you need to be more explicit in differentiating between OAuth and OAuth2. OpenID Connect is build on top of OAuth2.

Answer (score 6):

OAuth provides only and should only provides authorization using an access token. OpenID connect is built on OAuth 2 in order to provide user authentication information. OpenID connect is in fact the child of OpenID. [See OpenID-Connect-Lecture-for-MIT, slide 33](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025160551/http://fr.slideshare.net/zeronine1/open-id-connect-lecture-for-mit)

> OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749] protocol. It enables Clients to verify the identity of the End-User based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as well as to obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an interoperable and REST-like manner.
>    OpenID Connect Core 1.0 - draft 17

Things is, OpenID connect provides you a "standard" way to obtains user identity. If you use OAuth and the API, you should adapt your request for each ressources, which may not always provide the same information or may change over the time. And conceptually, you use OAuth to be allowed to use an API, not to authenticate an user.

> As background, the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework [RFC6749] and OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token Usage [RFC6750] specifications provide a general framework for third-party applications to obtain and use limited access to HTTP resources. They define mechanisms to obtain and use Access Tokens to access resources but do not define standard methods to provide identity information. Notably, without profiling OAuth 2.0, it is incapable of providing information about the authentication of an End-User. OpenID Connect Core 1.0 - draft 17

Note that, OpenID connect provides an id_token with some information about the user. But if you want the whole set of information, you still need the access_token to request the the OpenID provider to get the userinfo (which confuse me the first time I see it). See `5.3.1. userinfo request` in the draft

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: This answer doesn't mention how how they are different.

Comment: One is for authorization, one for authentication