# Why not oAuth for Authentication - AKA what is bad about OpenID Connect

Tags: oauth, openid, identification, openid-connect

I read many questions and answers on this forum stating that oAuth is for authorization, OpenID is for authentication and more than a few of them goes on to say that OpenID Connect provides authentication by abusing oAuth authorization.

Why the derogative tone?  There is a very strong implication that this is bad, but I have not found any explanations for this, and while I understand the difference between authentication and authorization, I don't understand where anybody would use authorization without authentication, or more accurately, without attributability.

Actually that's not true, if I try I can think of situations where attributability is not important, but that won't work for my situation:  I'm working on an online service which will allow registrations from users using FB, Twitter, Google+ and probably LinkedIn for authentication.  The Front-end applications (web based and mobile, potentially controlled by third parties) should from my understanding use oAuth for access to the API/back-end services on a user's behalf.

For example, if I get a request from a front-end mobile app or a web site to access a user's messages, maybe like:

https://api.example.com/en/messages/userXid&filter=unread

I would need to know that the user signed into the application or web-site is not just authorized to read the messages resource, but that it is in fact the user who may read that specific mailbox.

But I digress, so: Is OpenID Connect bad somehow?  I've seen the [Wikipedia diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) ... can someone please explain what is wrong with that picture?

I'm ultimately trying to figure out what are all the pieces of the puzzle to create an architechture where:

a) Users register on the back-end and are authenticated via 
    OpenID / Google / FB / etc
  b) Users access the service via an independent front-end, eg a 
    mobile app or web-site
  c) Different users have different roles (Eg Staff and Customers) and 
    can not access each other's personal or sensitive data
  d) It is a multi-tenant service, so Staff from company A could 
    actually be customers of company B and Company C!

FWIW: Some things that I've seen, which helps to confuse/clarify things for me:

- [oAuth 2.0 provides Authorization](http://oauth.net/about/)
- The page above says oAuth is meant to provide authorization without
  sharing identification; then how is attributability achieved?
- [OpenID Connect uses oAuth 2.0 and provides authentication](http://openid.net/connect/faq/)
- The page mentioned above states that oAuth 2.0 was designed to support
  development of Authorization **AND AUTHENTICATION PROTOCOLS**
- Does OpenID Connect then provide both Authentication AND Authorization?

Answer (score 1):

[Difference Between OAUTH, OpenID and OPENID Connect in very simple term?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44611/difference-between-oauth-openid-and-openid-connect-in-very-simple-term?rq=1)

Well this was on the side navbar.

It's like this:

If you are authorised to do activity A, you must possibly be the owner that can do activity A. Therefore you must be owner. Authorisation = Authentication. Whereas you could be authenticated but not authorised.

Comment: I see, so Maybe I need to experiment with the protocols, because I don't understand how a user can be authorized and you don't really KNOW who the user is.  I'm going to ask a separate question about this.

Comment: I've added a new related question here: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/79805/66581

Comment: Since obtaining the answer to my other question I am now even more strongly of the opinion that authorization without authenticated identification is only useful in a small set of cases - those where attributability is not important.  However identification is easily added to oAuth2.

Comment: This all seems irrelevant. What if you desire authentication ONLY, without essentially mining a user's data (which is what authorization actually means)? OpenID Connect seems to eliminate that option.